# 3d surface plot in R, with z dimension changing over time

Tags: r, rgl

I have a dataset with a x-y-z structure.

```
X = age of arrival in the city
Y = year of arrival
Z = number of current survivors from X/Y combination
```

I have no problem plotting this for any given time using RGL in R. However I would like to introduce a time dimension. 
I could of course make 23 plots and paste them together, but I would like to be able to manipulate the viewing on the fly, and treat the whole time series as one plot.  I have Z values for 23 years. I also would like to colour my plot with an extra z2 variable, being z_year/z_(year-1). Is this possible within the RGl pakcage with some programming or is there a better package available?

Answer (score 0):

[Try creating a video](http://www.example.com/) like described on SO..

Alternative is a for-loop with a plot and delaying it -> look at ?Sys.sleep